# Can I display custom tags of columns in a database diagram?

Tags: enterprise-architect, database-diagram

I am trying to use database diagrams in Sparx EA to collect and communicate information about how we are using tables.

I want to add information to columns and have this information show up in a diagram.

For example, the first thing I want to do is note which columns are required in a given application.

I have used the reverse-engineering to import all the many tables into my Sparx project.
It looks like I can extend column information with Tags at least.

But I can't find a way to show my custom tags in a diagram, such as a basic database diagram with tables.

- **Is there a way to visualize custom tag information for columns in a diagram?**

What seems like the most direct example would be such as the following, where a custom "usage" Tag appears after the column name and data type ...

[image: what I wish I could have in EA]

I welcome other options such as conditionally changing the color or font or something based on the Tag,
 if adding the Tag name & value is not possible.

Comment: No, you can't. The only things that you see there are think like type, default value, null/not null. This last one is normally how you indicate optional vs required.

Comment: Sure.  Of course, in this case I can't do it that way :) .   How about creating a new Stereotype or such?   I'm willing to try anything, but I don't easily find information how to do it.

Comment: I wouldn't do. Creating that with shapescript will not just ruin one of your days. You'd additionally need an add-in to create the string. And you can't format them in a tabular way.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on Shapescript.  Is that the only way to define a new Stereotype with my own display settings?